# vb.net memory usage

Tags: vb.net

my application is just s simple sendkeys. my problem is when i run my application it used for about 55-65k memory usage, then when i minimized it to system tray, it suddenly goes down to about 1-3k memory usage, then when i restore it again, it rise to about 6-8k memory usage. my question is how can i lower the memory usage even i dont minimized my application?

NOTE: i try to wait for about 3mins to see if my application will reduce it's memory usage, coz i think it's just loading some component. but i doesnt, i sit on 55-65k if i dont minimized it.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Integer) As Integer
    Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" Alias "keybd_event" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetForegroundWindow" () As IntPtr
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

    Private SearchWindow As String
    Public Const vbKeyQ = 81
    Public Const vbKeyW = 87
    Public Const vbKeyE = 69
    Public Const vbKeyR = 82
    Public Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SearchWindow = "MU"
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Then
            Dim ForeGroundHwnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow
            Dim MySearchWinow As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, SearchWindow)
            If ForeGroundHwnd = MySearchWinow Then
                If rbQ.Checked = True Then
                    keybd_event(vbKeyQ, 0, 0, 0)
                    keybd_event(vbKeyQ, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
                ElseIf rbW.Checked = True Then
                    keybd_event(vbKeyW, 0, 0, 0)
                    keybd_event(vbKeyW, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
                ElseIf rbE.Checked = True Then
                    keybd_event(vbKeyE, 0, 0, 0)
                    keybd_event(vbKeyE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
                ElseIf rbR.Checked = True Then
                    keybd_event(vbKeyR, 0, 0, 0)
                    keybd_event(vbKeyR, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        Try
            If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
                Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
                NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick
        Try
            Me.Show()
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

> when i minimized it to system tray, it suddenly goes down to about 1-3k memory usage

Clearly you are running on a very old operating system.  You are not measuring memory usage at all, you are looking at the *working set* of your program.  The number of virtual memory pages that are mapped into RAM.  On an old OS, like XP, the memory manager aggressively trims the working set of a process when its main window is minimized.  A feature that was designed to squeeze a lot of processes in very little RAM.  XP only requires 64 megabytes.

It doesn't come for free, it takes time for the process to get responsive when it gets the foreground again, those pages that were mapped out need to be paged back in.  That will at first only be the pages that are really needed by your code, that's why the increase isn't that large.  Modern versions of Windows no longer bother with this feature, they can count on machines having enough RAM these days. Windows only reduces the working set of a program when it needs to make room for other processes.  Doing work that is not needed is just wasted effort.

In reality, you are actually using a lot more memory than that.  Virtual memory.  It doesn't cost anything, it is virtual.  Compromising your code to reduce something that doesn't cost anything doesn't make sense.  And 65KB of virtual memory is peanuts, only 3% of what's available to a process.

A book like Windows Internals is a good one to learn more about the way memory is managed on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for an application to use memory that way.

When you minimise the application, the system sends a signal to the memory manager to try to release as much memory as possible.

Normally an application will not try to minimise the allocated memory, because that is just a waste of time. Having a lot of free memory doesn't make a computer run faster, on the contrary it would just do a lot of work for no reason. If you need the memory, the memory manager will try to free it.

For completeness, I should mention that you *could* make the application use less memory by forcing garbage collections, but that is pointless, and generally considered bad practice.